# RewriteRule to redirect to subdirectory based on HTTP_REFERER

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a problem where a wordpress install was moved from `/` (root) to `/beta/` (subdirectory).  I have it working great, except that there are some page links that are linking to, for instance, `/my-page` which is now a 404, and I want it to redirect to `/beta/my-page`.  These links *exist* on `/beta/(.*)` paths, so my thought was to make a `.htaccess` rule in the main root path that would see that a link came from `/beta/*` and simply redirect the user back to the proper page.  This is what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
# `HTTP_REFERER` contains my beta path...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} /march\-beta
# The current page is not *already* a `/march-beta` page (don't want an infinite redirect)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/march\-beta
# Remap the entire path to be in the correct subdirectory
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /march-beta$1 [R=302, L]
```

However... I'm getting a 500 server misconfiguration kind of error when I save the file in the webroot of the server.

An example:

If a user is on `/march-beta/t-shirts`

and clicks on a link that links to:  `/blue-t-shirts`  (or even `/t-shirts/blue-ones`)

I want the `.htaccess` file to see that the `HTTP_REFERER` contains `/march-beta` and immediately `R=302` them to `/march-beta/blue-t-shirts` (or `/march-beta/t-shirts/blue-ones`, in the second case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a 500 server error because you have a space between your rewrite flags. The space makes mod_rewrite think that the flags are `[R=302,` and that horribly confuses mod_rewrite and throws an error. Try removing the space:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /march-beta$1 [R=302,L]
```

Also, you're probably going to want a slash after `/march-beta` because the URI handed to rewrite *rule*'s in an htaccess file has the leading slash stripped off:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /march-beta/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Oh for the love of.  Figures it was something stupid.  Thanks for the note on the leading slash, although I would have figured that out easily when the rewrite rule was redirecting me to "march-betat-shirts" or whatever.  A space between the flags >.<  That's all it was!  Thanks a bunch haha.